# How to Create Virtual Environment by using Command?

Tags: python

In my computer has already installed python 3.11.4 and python 3.12 (latest version).
But provided path in "Edit the system environment variable" 3.12 only.
(Unchecked "Add Python 3.11 to PATH" check box when Install Python 3.11.4)

I need to create virtual environment for some project by using python 3.11 version.
So, that's why I installed 3.11.4 version too.

After that, I tried to create virtual environment with execute the following command in CMD :

```
python3 -m venv --python=C:\Python\Python311 MyVenv
```

(And also tried with this command :)

```
python3.11 -m venv MyVenv
```

But it gave me Error as follows :

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, 
or disable this shortcut from   Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

When I try to create VENV by using 3.12 version It was successfully created !

Q :
How to control multi-version of python same local machine ?
How to create VENV with my prefer virsion in multi-version installed machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Command for 3.11 :

C:\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv MyVenv

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Pramu's answer above, if you'll frequently be using multiple versions of Python, it might be easier to create shortcuts to the specific versions of Python through batch files. For example, in a directory that you've added to the `PATH`, create a file named `python311.bat`. In it, add the following:

```
@echo off
C:\Python\Python311\python.exe %*
```

You can then call it the same way you would an ordinary Python command:

```
python311 -m venv MyVenv
```

You would do the same with Python 3.12.